# Shopware 6 dynamic prices per customer via API

Tags: shopware6

I would like to display different prices based on customer.
Reading the documentation [here](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/v/6.4/guides/plugins/plugins/api/customer-specific-pricing), says that I need to use commercial plugin for this feature.

Is there any way to implement dynamic prices via API without the use of a shopware plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [advanced pricing](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/catalogues/products#advanced-pricing) of products to create a price that only becomes active when the conditions of a rule are met. You create the rule in the [Rule Builder](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/rules) with one or multiple [conditions that can only match a single customer](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/rules#customers). You could do so by matching the email or address of the customer. The price you set in the advanced pricing would then only become available to that one customer, once they're logged in.

This method has the downside of having to create many rules for many different customers and then having to map those rules to specific prices. The commercial feature is far better suited, if you plan to introduce customer specific prices in a big way.